# error while installing nodejs package db-oracle on windows 7

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install oracle package on my windows environment and getting following error. Did someone tried on installing on their machine and how to fix this issue

```
C:\Users>npm install db-oracle
npm WARN package.json mongo@0.1.0 No repository field.  
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle  
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle  

db-oracle@0.2.3 install C:\Users\vishaltyagi\node_modules\db-oracle
node-waf configure build  
'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  

db-oracle@0.2.3 preuninstall C:\Users\vishaltyagi\node_modules\db-oracle   
rm -rf build/*   
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

npm WARN continuing anyway undefined  
npm ERR! weird error 1  
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means the module was probably written for a version before v0.8, where `node-waf` was removed. `node-waf` was a build tool for compiling native addon modules that was superseded by `node-gyp`, which uses a `binding.gyp` file, instead of a `wscript` file.

The easiest way to fix this would be to install `node-waf` on Linux by finding the package `nodejs-dev`, which will add the command to your PATH. A more complex way to is to convert the `wscript` file [here](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle/blob/master/wscript) to `binding.gyp` format.

Comment: Does it work on windows environment. My requirement is specific to Windows OS

Comment: It was built for Windows, but unofficially. You'd have to find the builds, because it has been discontinued anyways. You should just convert the module from using `node-waf` to `node-gyp`.